# Can't get google search results using python and VS Code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

First of all, I'm quite new to this.
I have been trying to use Python to get some Google search results, and I'm trying to use a modified version of the code from [Unable to get google search results python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183863/unable-to-get-google-search-results-python). I am reaching the same results as the previous post and the suggested solutions don't seem to be working

The code I am using is

```
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=wikipedia&num=10"
requests_results=requests.get(url)
soup_result = BeautifulSoup(requests_results.content, "html.parser")
links = soup_result.find_all('a')
```

However, this is not working as it retrieves urls for Google privacy policies.

The interesting thing is that I am trying to run this code in VS Code with no avail, but when I use Google Colabs this works fine and I can't figure out why.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify things, Google isn't really cool with us scraping their search results directly. It's against their policy and they have some pretty smart systems in place to stop it. What you're experiencing (getting those links to Google's privacy policies) is Google's way of telling you that it knows you're trying to scrape and it's not providing the data you want.

On the other hand, Google offers a couple of legit ways to pull search results:

- **Google Custom Search JSON API**: It's a neat, paid service that lets you make your own search engine that pulls from websites you specify (could be your own website or other public ones). You'll get results in a user-friendly JSON format.
- **Google Search API**: A slightly more advanced, and also paid, option. It lets you take search results from Google Search and bake them right into your own application.

As for why your code is behaving differently in VS Code vs Google Colabs, my guess is it's because Google Colabs is run on Google's own infrastructure. Google's servers might be more forgiving of scraping attempts coming from in-house, but this isn't something to rely on.